# database design table with a lot columns

Tags: sql-server, database-design

I have a survey to do. 30 more yes/no questions(has 4 types A,B,C,D). if answer is no, user should give reason. I am thinking create a table which has 30 more column for the answer, the column name are like 
`A1,A2...A7,B1,B2,...C1,C2...D1,D2...D8.`

Their datatype is bit. And I create another table just for comments with 1:1 relation. Column name like

```
'A1Cm,A2Cm,...A7Cm,B1Cm.....D8Cm'
```

I don't think it is a good design. But it is the easiest way to load to data to asp.net page.
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option 1:

```
QuestionId - int primary key, 
QuestionType - bit - A1,A2...A7,B1,B2,...C1,C2...D1,D2...D8 
QuestionComment - varchar
```

Option 2:

You may consider adding `QuestionType` and/or `QuestionComment` table:

**QuestionTable:**

```
QuestionId - int primary key, 
QuestionTypeId - int (forigen key QuestionType(Id))
QuestionCommentId - int (forigen key QuestionComment(Id))
```

**QuestionType:**

```
Id 
QuestionType
```

**QuestionComment:**

```
Id
QuestionComment:
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be much better to create a question table to describe each question and a user table to describe each user. Then a third table to handle relationship of a user to their answers. Something like:

```
user( user_id, name, date_answered, ... )
question( question_id, question_type, name, question_text, ... )
answer( user_id, question_id, answer, comment, ... )
```

The user_id column would be auto-generated for each user session.

Example data would look like:

```
user( 555, "Some User", 2013-10-19 )
question ( 1, "A", "Dog question", "Do you like dogs?" )
answer( 555, 1, "NO", "I am afraid of them" )
```